# How to reduce cpu usage in a c application?

Tags: c

Im trying to do a simple server application, so i need to loop until theres a connection then loop again, etc... but when i do that, i get 50-100% cpu usage, while im using mutexes & conditions, is there any way to avoid this using posix threads (pthreads) in c? if so, can you please give an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380926/pthread-mutex-lock-100-cpu - Why the duplication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it's difficult to answer, but it sounds like you are using [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting).
In pseudo-code:
Busy waiting:

```
while (no connection) {
    check connection;
}
```

Better:

```
while (no connection) {
    sleep(100);
    check connection;
}
```

Comment: Use select instead of a CPU cycle hogging busy loop. select will block your program (i.e. it will not use CPU resources) until something interesting happens on the socket.

Comment: `sleep()` is not the answer, it's a kludge.  Instead of `sleep()`, wait for a connection at that point (which might be implemented using `select()` / `poll()`, or maybe `pthread_cond_wait()`, or perhaps something else).

Comment: @caf & @datenwolf : i have used select and it works fine too, thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is called busy waiting.. it isn't a good idea. 
If you are waiting for socket event, use a select function instead.

Busy waiting is never a good solution. If you use the select, then your program will be waked when an event occured on a given file descriptor (or socket).